# Svelte Writable Stores n+1 vs n++

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Working through the official svelte example of writable-stores https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

Wondering why this works in updating count

```js
    function increment() {
        count.update((n) => n+1);
    }
```

and this does not?

```js
    function increment() {
        count.update((n) => n++);
    }
```

Comment: You apparenty do not understand postfix notation.  If `n` is 5, then `n+1` has the value 6, whereas `n++` has the value 5.  Probably what you want is `++n` (assuming you want to change `n` at all).

Comment: @ArfurNarf You apparently do not understand that you did not need to start your comment with "You apparently do not understand postfix notation." You also didn't explain postfix vs prefix and it's a reasonable assumption that tutorial's `increment()` method is intended to change `n`.

Comment: Why 'reasonable assumption'?  The first case does not change `n`.  I'd suppose the purpose was to update `count`, not change an argument as a side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n++` is a *post*-increment operator. It returns the current value, then increments the variable. In this case, you want to use the *pre*-increment operator, which looks like `++n`. It first increments the value, then returns the already incremented value.

```js
function increment() {
    count.update((n) => ++n);
}
```

[Javascript increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)